# Equivalence between Ehresmann and Koszul definition of linear connection

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, connections

I was taught, in different courses, the following definitions of connection.

> An Ehresmann connection on a fibre bundle $\pi:B\rightarrow M$ is a distribution $H\hookrightarrow TB$ such that:
> $$\forall b\in B\quad T_bB=H_b\oplus V_b(\pi)$$
> where $V_b(\pi)\subset TB$ is the subspace of vertical vectors at $b\in B$: $$V_bB=\{v\in T_bB| T_b\pi(v)=0\in T_{\pi(b)}(M)\}$$
> We can identify an Ehresmann connection with a map $\omega: TM\rightarrow TB$ as follows
> Fix $H$, $u\in T_bB$, $v=T_b\pi(u)\in T_{\pi(b)}M$. Then $u\equiv u_{(H)}\oplus u_{(V)}$.
> Call $\tilde{v}:=u_{(H)}$ the horizontal lift of $v$, this is uniquely defined: $u'\in(T_b\pi)^{-1}(v)\Rightarrow T_b\pi(u-u')=v-v=0 \Rightarrow u-u'\in V_b(\pi)\Rightarrow u_{(H)}=u'_{(H)}$
> Consequently an Ehresmann connection defines  $\omega_H:TM\rightarrow TB$, fiberwise:
> $$\forall b\in B,\ (\omega_H)_b:T_{\pi(b)}M\rightarrow T_bB\quad\ v\in T_{\pi(b)}M\mapsto \tilde{v}\in T_bB$$
> such that $T_b\pi\circ\omega_H=id_{TM}$.
> Conversely,any such map determines an Ehresmann connection $H_\omega$, by setting
> $$(H_\omega)_b =\{u\in T_bB:\ u\in Im(\omega_b)\}$$
> Such a map $\omega$ makes the following Witney sequence split:
> $$0\longrightarrow VB(\pi)\longrightarrow TB\xrightarrow{T\pi}TM\longrightarrow 0$$
> Now given a (local) vector field $\xi\in\chi(U)$, we can lift its values through $\omega$ to a vector field $\xi_H$ valued in $TB$, in coordinates:
> $$\xi_H(x,y)=\xi^\mu(x)(\partial_{x^\mu}(x)-\Gamma^i_\mu(x,y)\partial_{y^i}(x,y))$$
> Recalling that upon fibred coordinate change $(x,y)\mapsto(x'(x),y'(x,y))$:
> \begin{cases}
>  \partial_{x^\mu}=J^\nu_\mu\partial_{x'^\nu}+J^i_\mu\partial_{y'^i}\\
>  \partial_{y^i}=J^j_i\partial_{y'^j}
>  \end{cases}
> Thence an Ehresmann connection is determined by:
> \begin{cases}
>  \Gamma^i_\mu:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
>  \Gamma'^i_\mu(x',y')=\bar{J}^\nu_\mu((J^i_j(x,y)\Gamma^j_\nu(x,y)-J^i_\nu)\quad\quad (x,y)\mapsto(x'(x),y'(x,y))
>  \end{cases}
> where $J^\nu_\mu=\partial_{x^\mu}(x'^\nu(x)), J^i_j=\partial_{y^j}y'^i(x,y),J^i_\nu=\partial_{x^\nu}y'^i(x,y)$ and $\bar{J}^\nu_\mu=(J^\nu_\mu)^{-1}$

Now in the case $E$ is a vector bundle, it makes sense to speak of

> A linear Ehresmann connection on a vector bundle $E$ is a connection whose coefficients, in any system of fibred coordinates $(x,y)$ are linear in the fiber coordinates, i.e.
> $$\Gamma^i_\alpha(x,y)=\Gamma^i_{j\alpha}(x)y^j$$.

Now, I would like to see that this notion of linear connection is equivalent to the one I am used to, the Koszul definition of connection:

> Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle. A linear connection on $E$ is a mapping:
> $$\nabla:\chi(M)\times\Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(E)\quad (X,V)\mapsto \nabla_XV$$
> such that:
> 1 $\nabla_XV$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in $X$, i.e.
> $$\nabla_{f_1X_1+f_2X_2}V=f_1\nabla_{X_1}V+f_2\nabla_{X_2}V\quad\quad\forall X_1,X_2\in C^\infty(M)\forall V\in\Gamma(E)$$
> 2 $\nabla_XV$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear in $V$, i.e.
> $$\nabla_{X}(a_1V_1+a_2V_2)=a_1\nabla_XV_1+a_2\nabla_XV_2\quad\quad\forall a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}\forall V_1,V_2\in\Gamma(E)$$
> 3 $\nabla$ satisfies the Leibniz rule, i.e.
> $$\nabla_X(fV)=f\nabla_XV+(Xf)V$$

How can one proceed to do so? Is the operator I asked about in [Eheresmann connection and covariant derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018181/eheresmann-connection-and-covariant-derivative) involved?